# Angular How to get the video ID from a full YouTube URL

Tags: angularjs

In my data object I have a full YouTube URL (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ9g_-p3dLA).

In my partial I need to extract the video ID from this string (kJ9g_-p3dLA). I'm trying not to resort to running through all my data when the app starts and extracting the video ID through that way.

I'm looking for a filter or a directive that I can feed the full YouTube ID to which will return the video ID. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up writing my own filter for this:

```
app.filter("GetYouTubeID", function ($sce) {
  return function (text) {
      var video_id = text.split('v=')[1].split('&')[0];
      return video_id;
  }
})
```

Can be used in a partial like so:

```
{{content.complete_youtube_url | GetYouTubeID}}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Pugh, oversight due to Friday evenings... :) Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id = "demo" />
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var url= "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ9g_-p3dLA"; //sample url
    var res = str.split("http://www.youtube.com/watch?").splice("1");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = url;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions, which have no dependencies on Angular.

Note that I'm not a regex expert so my expression may not be *perfect*.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(?:\?v=)([^&]+)(?:\&)*/);
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ9g_-p3dLA";
var matches = regex.exec(url);

var videoId = matches[1]; // kJ9g_-p3dLA
```

That regex will capture a group between ?v= and & (the & is optional).

Comment: Thanks- that part I actually got already. I was trying to find a way to do this in a way that I can use this in an Angular template. Check out my answer for how I ended up doing it.

Comment: @Squrler Misunderstood your question, oops! I thought you were asking how to split the ID out, not how to do it automagically in Angular land :P

Answer (score -4):

Test with explode function of PHP

$youtubre_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ9g_-p3dLA";

$array_id = explode("=",$youtubre_url);
$id = $array_id[1];